# Natural alternative for built

Tags: synonyms

Sample sentence - A cave was _________ into the cliff.

I'm trying to say that the cave was built naturally without any human intervention in any way.

The alternatives I can think/search of - carved, cut, built, slice but all of do carry a connotation of having human involvement.

Feel free to modify the sentence. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The cave was carved out of cliff by waves. No human involvement at all.

Comment: Nature had carved a cave into the cliff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could say that the cave formed, as in

> Caves form naturally by the weathering of rock and often extend deep underground. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave)

However, I disagree with your assessment that the words you listed imply human involvment. The rock can be carved out by glaciers, rivers, or the *elements* in general.

Comment: I'm not saying that the words absolutely mean human involvement...that's why I say "carry a connotation". If you were to say "A cave was carved into the cliff", I, for one, would assume that humans had helped shape the cave...

Comment: If it's important to differentiate between naturally occurring and man-made caves, you could qualify your sentence by adding how the cave was created: "A cave was carved into the cliff *by a prehistoric river*" (or whatever applies in your case)

Comment: see that's the thing, I can't write that because I don't know how it was created. In the sentence, I just mention that the cave was present in the cliff and that it was naturally formed.

Comment: If you wrote "a cave formed in the cliff", I'd think it occurred naturally, without external intervention.

Answer (score 0):

If the cliff was by the sea and it was the action of waves which had formed the cave you could say that it had been *eaten* into the cliff. This would certainly not have implications of human involvement since no humans eat rock.

Answer (score 0):

> A **prehistoric** cave in the cliff offered us shelter.

I think prehistoric *implies strongly* it was not made by humans, but I admit slightly ambiguous compared to the other answers.